# I am getting this error unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

Why I am getting this error I am creating a bmi calculator:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

Code snippet:

```
Height= input("Enter Height in meter")
Weight= input (" Enter Weight in Kg ")
Result = int(weight)/int(height**2)
Print(result)
```

Comment: `int(height**2)` should be `int(height)**2`. You're trying to square a string, which is exactly what the error message you posted is telling you.

Comment: or you could use `int(input("Enter Height in meter")) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` [returns a string, which has to be converted into a number.](https://www.codesdope.com/course/python-input/#:%7E:text=Taking%20Integer%20Input%20in%20Python&text=We%20can%20do%20this%20by,using%20the%20int()%20function.&text=int()%20changes%20a%20string,give%20us%20an%20integer%2012.)

So like

```py
height= int(input("Enter Height in meter"))
weight= int(input (" Enter Weight in Kg "))
result = weight/(height**2)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you enter in `input()` gets converted into a string.
You can convert height into an integer `int(height)**2` or simply convert input to integer that instance `int(input("Enter Height in meter"))`

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error always when I work with inputs.
The best answer is to call a function. Look at my work below.

```
def float_int(asked):
    if "." in asked:
        asked = float(asked)
    else:
        asked = int(asked)
```

And the next time you use an input, call it a name such as "ask_one" and insert it into the argument. It's supposed to work. Look below again.

```
ask_one = input("Insert Value")
float_int(ask_one)
```

Hope this helped(:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).